# insert into MySQl table elements from php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, foreach

So guys i have this array  that i need to insert into my db. I'm using foreach but i can't get it to run with two values.

The simple array looks like this:

```
    Array
(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_produs] => 'value'
            [id_pret] => 'value'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_produs] => 'value'
            [id_pret] => 'value'
        )
.
.
.
    [i] => Array
        (
            [id_produs] => 'value'
            [id_pret] => 'value'
        )


)
```

This is what I got right now:

```
foreach ($vl['id_produs'] as $prds=>$val) 
        {
       if($val<>'') mysql_query("INSERT into db set  id_pachet='".$id_pachet."', id_produs='".$val."'"); 
        foreach ($vl['id_pret'] as $prdsv=>$valv) {
            if($valv<>'') mysql_query("INSERT into db  set id_pachet='".$id_pachet."',  id_pret='".$valv."'");
        }
        }
```

where:

```
$vl = array();
    $vl = $_POST;
```

What do I do wrong?

The hole array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [nume_pachet] => Test pachet nou
    [id_produs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 41
            [2] => 135
        )

    [id_pret] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 157
        )

    [pret_pachet] => 99.00
    [id_moneda] => 1
    [descriere_pachet] => Lorem ipsum dolores
    [activ] => 1
)
```

The db in which I want to insert the values has this structure:

id
id_pachet
id_produs
id_pret

so In one package (id_pachet) I can have more products (id_produs) which can have more than one price (id_pret)

for example:

```
id  id_pachet   id_produs   id_pret
1   3       13              1
2   3       13              2
3   3       14              0
```

The thing is that if do this:

```
foreach ($vl['id_produs'] as $prds=>$val) 
     {
   if($val<>'') mysql_query("INSERT into erad_produse_pachete_str set id_pachet='".$id_pachet."',  id_produs='".$val."'"); 

    }
```

it's working for id_produs, but i need to insert at the same time also id_pret

UPDATE!

I got some help from my brother. And this is working for me. If you can apply it for your case I hope it helps

```
$produse = $_POST['id_produs'];
$preturi = $_POST['id_pret'];


if(count($produse))
foreach ($produse as $key=>$id_produs) {

    if($id_produs>0){
        $id_pret = isset($preturi[$key]) ? $preturi[$key] : 0;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO erad_produse_pachete_str (id_pachet,id_produs,id_pret) VALUES ('{$id_pachet}', '{$id_produs}', '{$id_pret}')"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have wrong insert query ? see here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check your insert query, it's wrong.

For example, it should be,
`INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,.....) VALUE (value1, value2,.....)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong:

- the values of id_produs are numerics, you must not quote them
- the syntax of the insert query is wrong
- the loop over the foreach was not correct.

This should get you going:

```
foreach ($vl['id_produs'] as $val) {
  if($val<>'') 
    mysql_query("INSERT into `db` ( id_produs ) VALUES( $val )"); 
}

foreach ($vl['id_pret'] as $valv) {
  if($valv<>'') 
    mysql_query("INSERT into `db` ( id_pret ) VALUES( $valv )");
}
```

Comment: The db in which I want to insert the values has this structure:

id
id_pachet
id_produs
id_pret

so In one package (id_pachet) I can have more products (id_produs) which can have more than one price (id_pret)

for example:`code

id id_pachet id_produs id_pret
1 3  13  1
2 3  13  2
3 3  14  0`

Comment: I can't get this right in this comment. So I'll edit my question

Comment: @JvdBerg can I do a foreach for two values? something like this: foreach ($vl['id_produs'] as $val and $vl['id_pret'] as $valv )